# Pay product in e-commerce web with a real TPV, no virtual TPV

Tags: web-services, web, payment-gateway, credit-card

I would know if pay a product in a e-commerce web with a real (no virtual) TPV is posible.

I can use some CMS like Drupal or Prestashop.

Perhaps the easiest solution is to use web services to communicate with desktop application that uses the TPV API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a prestashop module [TPV phisical store for prestashop](http://www.pos-tpv.com/en/home/8-pos-physical-store-for-prestashop.html)